# Open electronic lock with EMP

Tags: solenoid, pulse, electromagnetic, induction

Would be possible open a electronic lock, like that used in door, through induction using an EMP device?

Comment: With enough induction you might be able to melt the whole lock or weld it closed permanently. How long is a piece of string?

Comment: Anything is possible

Answer (score 2):

That depends entirely on the lock philosophy. What is the desired failure mode? For most electronic locks the idea is that the door should be locked as a default, so such mechanisms would fail in the locked condition. For example, if a solenoid is used to lock the door, the solenoid is spring-loaded to engage the lock and requires power to retract it, and an EMP would presumably destroy the power source and the solenoid would remain inactivated. The door stays locked.

On the other hand, it's perfectly possible to design a locking mechanism which is intended to fail unlocked, and this is the norm for things like school access doors. Here the criterion is safety in an emergency, such as a fire, and any interruption of power will result in the doors unlocking to let people out. In the case of a solenoid-operated lock, the solenoid would be spring-loaded to retract, and constant power would be required to keep the door in the locked condition.

So there is no single, simple answer to your question. As in so many things, it depends.